# Difference between 火花 and スパーク

Tags: english-to-japanese, loanwords, japanese-to-english

1. When talking about sparks, what is the difference between 火花 and スパーク?
2. If I want to describe a spark of static electricity, which word is better to use?
3. Can either of these words be used metaphorically (e.g. spark of inspiration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red stuffs that come out of a hot or burning object are almost always called 火花. スパーク is relatively uncommon and usually refers to 放電 or electrical sparks/discharge (typically blue). デジタル大辞泉 [defines](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF/) スパーク as 放電などによって火花が出ること.

[image]
Left: 火花; Right: スパーク

[火花を散らす](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%81%AB%E8%8A%B1%E3%82%92%E6%95%A3%E3%82%89%E3%81%99) is a common set phrase, and people sometimes say (議論が)スパークする, but I cannot think of other common metaphors. Of course you can directly say 火花のような○○ or such.